# Context Menu background coloring

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm having a bit of trouble with a context menu that I'm trying to create in XAML.  It should be fairly simple, just a list of menuitems, with occasional separators.

I've been able to get it arranged correctly, all the items are in the correct spot, and now I'm moving on to styling and theming it.  We theme by exposing a number of named brushes that are swapped out at an application-level, so in my styles for the contextmenu, menuitem, and separator controls I bind to those names as dynamic resources.  So far, all of this is bog-standard.

The issue I'm seeing is that for my separators I have a chunk of space on the left side of the context menu that doesn't show the same background as the rest of the menu, which is very visually distracting.  You can see an example, and image how it gets worse on our darker themes!

[image: Imgur]

And in our dark style:

[image: Imgur]

Here is the style I'm using for the contextmenu and the separator:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContextMenu.IsOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundLight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundText}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Grid Margin="0,6,0,4" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Rectangle Margin="30,0,1,1" Height="1" Fill="{DynamicResource BackgroundLight}"/>
                    <Rectangle Margin="30,1,1,0" Height="1" Fill="{DynamicResource ContextMenuSeparator}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have no idea where this darn thing is coming from, and when I Snoop the app's visual tree I just see a ContentPresenter with a white Canvas that I have no idea how to remove.  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: See [Menu Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296.aspx)

Comment: @sll so you're thinking I can override the contextmenu's ControlTemplate with something that uses my theme colors for the Border property, like shown in that example, and that may fix it?

Comment: @ChesterHusk From what I can see online, it looks like you have to edit the Templates to get rid of that space.

Comment: You both were very helpful.  I finally got around to tinkering with the ControlTemplates that are generated by default in Blend for these controls to get the desired background behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Good sir, you should be able to get your desired behavior through [MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.separatorstylekey.aspx).

The **default style** appears to be something along the lines of:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,4,2,3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <theme:ClassicBorderDecorator BorderStyle="HorizontalLine"
                                              BorderBrush="{x:Static theme:ClassicBorderDecorator.ClassicBorderBrush}"
                                              BorderThickness="1"/>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You may be able to induce a hack via the ClassicBorderBrush's Background property. (TemplateBinding?)